# GraphicsMagick and grunt-responsive-image - engine: 'im' breaks task

Tags: gruntjs, imagemagick, asset-pipeline, graphicsmagick

**Goal** - I am setting up an asset pipeline using grunt to convert and compress image files for a website.

**Issue** - grunt-responsive-images fails to find gm/convert.

`Warning: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: identify "-ping" "-format" "%m:%T:%s" "src/css/images/test.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found`

GraphicsMagick is installed, and I am able to call `gm version` from the same directory:

`GraphicsMagick 1.3.25 2016-09-05 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/`

If I comment out the **`engine: 'im'`** line below, the task runs and size and compression settings are applied.

```
grunt.initConfig({
responsive_images: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      // engine: 'im',    <--does this invoke gm?
      sizes: [{
        name: 'small',
        width: '30%',
        suffix: '_small',
        quality: 60
      },{
        name: 'large',
        width: '50%',
        suffix: '_large',
        quality: 40
      }]
    },
```

**Question 1** - What is **engine: 'im'** doing?

**Question 2** - How is grunt-responsive-images resizing and compressing images files when **engine: 'im'** isn't specified? Is it using built-in image tools?

**UPDATE**

When I changed `engine: 'im'` to `engine: 'gm'`, the tasks completed with no errors. Maybe `im = imageMagick` and `gm = graphicsMagick`? Also, maybe, grunt-responsive-images can find gm, but cannot find im?

**Question 3** - How would I fix grunt-responsive-images to work with imageMagick (like I see in many tutorials)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @fmw42 I _thought_ I had installed ImageMagick via homebrew, but when I tried `brew list` the package was not listed. Doh! After running `brew install imagemagick`... it's working with both 'im' and 'gm' engine properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers in the documentation: [grunt-responsive-images\options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-responsive-images#options)

**Answer 1** - 
options.engine: Chooses which graphics engine to use when resizing images. To use GraphicsMagick, **set this to gm. To use ImageMagick, set this to im.** You'll need the relevant engine installed.

**Answer 2** -
I had gm installed via npm, and grunt-responsive-images was using that to compress and resize. I *did not* have imagemagick installed. `brew list` did not show imagemagick (graphicsmagick was listed, and probably why I *thought* I had installed imagemagick).

**Answer 3** - The fix is simple; install imagemagick with homebrew:

`brew install imagemagick` then check with `brew list`. Now grunt runs with either 'gm' or 'im' engines selected.